# theme - pressed color of TextView in ListView only

Tags: android, listview, textview, themes

I'm trying to create an own theme which customizes all ListViews. I works perfectly fine for the selector but I want that the TextView color doesn't change to black when the ListView item is pressed (because the list selector is dark enough).

Here's what I tried. `textColor` in `MyListView` has no effect either. I also tried to define a drawable selector for `textColor` which uses white for all states, still no effect.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
</style>

<style name="MyListView" parent="@style/ICSListView_Dark">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/NoHighlightListTextView</item>
</style>

<style name="NoHighlightListTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Is it event possible? It would be an big overhead to hack the color in code. I feel like there's still something I didn't understand. So...

**How do I define a general theme for ListViews so the pressed color of the TextViews is white (instead black)?**

---

**Edit**

After some reading I came to the conclusion that it is impossible to achieve that the way I describe. You can set `textColor` globally in `MyTheme` but then it affects all TextViews. Or you create an own list item layout which behaves the right way. But you can't modify the default android list item with a theme definition. That seems to be logical if I think about it again... A TextView should check if it is nested in a ListView otherwise and that will never happen.